# java linux terminal -cp auto-complete

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, java, auto-completion

I'm working with a java library which needs two files 'library.jar' and 'library-extensions.jar'. Whenever I try to include both of them separated by a colon (e.g. -cp "library.jar:library-extensions.jar") and try to use auto-complete on the second jar file, it substitutes the first argument for the second one.

i.e.

I have something like this:

```
java -cp "library.jar:l
```

I press 'Tab' to auto-complete the second argument and it changes to:

```
java -cp "l
```

Is there anything I can do to enable proper auto-complete on additional arguments?

I'm using terminal on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Bash will autocomplete in general inside quotes. If you leave the quotes out it will autocomplete filenames in the current directory:

```
$ java -cp l<TAB>
library.jar  library-extensions.jar
$ java -cp library.jar:l<TAB>
library.jar  library-extensions.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Btw it does auto-complete the first argument in quotes(at least on my system), just not the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

To use use this, you need an other shell. It works great with [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
sudo chsh "$USER" -s $(which zsh)
```

Once you open up a new terminal window, it should load `zsh`.

---

*Example*

*with `zsh` and [Antigen<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen)*

[image]

Type <kbd>a</kbd>

[image]

Type <kbd>Tab</kbd>

[image]

Type <kbd>Tab</kbd> again

[image]

And again

[image]